# Pygame- Screen.blit(source, dest, area) returns empty rectangle

Tags: pygame, display, rect

I'm trying to make an animation in which an image simultaneously moves downwards and disappears, like this:

[image]

However, I can't seem to get this to work properly. I only want the part of the screen with the animation to change, so I did something like this...

```
orect = pygame.Rect(oSprite.rect)
    for i in range(10):
        screen.fill(Color(255,255,255),rect=orect)
        oSprite.rect.top += 12
        print(orect)
        print(screen.blit(oSprite.image, oSprite.rect, orect))
        pygame.display.update(orect)
        timer.tick(30)
```

where `oSprite` is the Sprite representing the image I want to animate.

In the docs, `screen.blit(source, dest, area)` should return a Rect representing the pixels that changed, but when I run my code, I get this (10 times over):

```
<rect(336, 48, 76, 74)>
<rect(336, 60, 0, 0)>
```

The second line is what was returned by `screen.blit()`, meaning that it changed a 0x0 area, and indeed, all I see onscreen when the code is running is a sudden cut to white, rather than any animation at all. Why might this occur? As seen from the first print() statement, the rect that I entered for the area value was 76x74, not 0x0.

Comment: I get the same result- just a cut to white.

Comment: Ok sorry, Probably I haven't understand what you are trying to achieve. You have an image surface right (oSprite.image)? And you want to blit inside it?

Comment: I'm trying to blit `oSprite.image` to `screen`, within the parameters of `orect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to blit on top of the oSprite.image surface, not the screen's surface.

This will draw another image on top of **oSprite.image** without extending on the screen if it is bigger.

```py
oSprite.image.blit(new_image, (0,0))
```

**Edited:**
Take this exmple, run it and see what is happening:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
run    = True

#Animation Speed
speed = 0.1

#Load an image.
player = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert_alpha()
x,y    = (0,0)

#Create a rectangular area to blit the player inside.
surf = pygame.Surface((player.get_width(),player.get_height()))


def Animate():
    global y

    if y > player.get_width():
        y = 0

    else:
        y += speed

while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            run=False
            break;


    #Clear the surface where you draw the animation.
    surf.fill((255,255,255))

    #Draw the image inside the surface.
    surf.blit(player, (x,y))

    #Draw that surface on the screen.
    screen.blit(surf, (20,20))

    #Animate the image.
    Animate()

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()




pygame.quit()
```

Imagine that **surf** is a piece of paper and you draw inside it the **image** and then you put that piece of paper on the screen.

Comment: Wouldn't that require me to make a new image for every frame of the animation? I just want the sprite to move downwards, and for only the area in `orect` to be changed during animation.

Comment: I got it sorted, thanks. I misunderstood what you meant originally.